# Using AutomationElement in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, dll, reference, ui-automation

I'm trying to use the [AutomationElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx) object for UIAutomation in C# but it is not being recognized. I'm guessing it's not part of the standard library since I'm getting a hint by Visual Studio saying that I might be missing a reference, but which reference do I need to add to use the AutomationElement?

I've tried UIAutomationClient but it didn't work even though this is what should contain AutomationElement according to the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx).

Hope someone can help

Comment: You need UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the link you posted you have all the info, you need to add a reference to UIAutomationClient (right click on project references) and add the namespace System.Windows.Automation to your source

[image: add reference]
[image: add namespace]